# Disable animation for "Swipe between full-screen apps"?

Tags: macos, mouse, magic-trackpad, gesture

Mavericks (Mac OS X 10.9.5) and Yosemite (10.10) offer a [mouse and trackpad gesture](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4721), *Swipe between full-screen apps*. Works well as full-screen apps are treated like a *Mission Control* desktop.

- Magic Trackpad – Three finger swipe to the right or left.
- Magic Mouse – Two finger swipe to the right or left.

[image]

[image: screen shot of System Preferences > Mouse > More Gestures > "Swipe between full-screen apps" checkbox]

The problem is the animation of the full-screen app sliding to the left or right as the other app/desktop/space slides alongside it. All this sliding makes me dizzy or nauseous. Especially bad during presentations to an audience, when I switch between [*Keynote*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keynote_(presentation_software)) app and other apps.

➥ Any way to disable or alter this left/right sliding animation?

➥ Is there some other way to switch between full-screen apps?

## Between, Not Into, Full-Screen Apps

This question is not a duplicate of questions such as [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128717/how-to-disable-full-screen-animation-on-os-x-10-9) that ask about disabling the animation *into* full-screen mode. My question is about the animation switching ("swiping") *between* full-screen app(s).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Sys Pref > `Reduce motion`

You can replace the horizontal sliding screen effect with a **gentle fade-in**, where one screen translucently covers and replaces the other. Works on macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

A faster/slower swipe of your fingers make a faster/slower fade-in. You can even stop mid-swipe to show the other screen translucently covering the present screen.

Choose `System Preferences` > `Accessibility` > `Display` > `Reduce motion`.

[image: screen shot of System Preferences, Accessibility, Reduce motion checkbox]

Comment: So happy that Apple's finally introduced this option to OS X.

Comment: OMG, my life will never be the same. Thank you!

Comment: This has no effect for me on 11.6 Big Sur. I still see the slide-y animation.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the animation speed by not swiping your fingers as fast. The actual code is quite tightly coupled into the OS and there's been no signs of people finding a hidden setting to speed up or even change the animations.

You could also use mission control to have the screen animation come down from above if the nausea is caused by left-right visual motion.

Lastly, if you really need to control the motion, you might have to pre-record the screen and just speak to it. Keynote and editing the video would allow you to fade to black or use another transition idiom than a wipe.