# skip full-screen animation in Catalina and Big Sur

Tags: catalina, big-sur, fullscreen, animation

In macOS 10.15.4+, when you make a window fullscreen, an animation about a second long zooms the window to the new size, and then the window rerenders (for example, a web browser or a Terminal).  Can this happen **faster**?

System Preferences > Display > Accessibility > Reduce Motion just replaces the animation with a crossfade that is equally slow.

Various [answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128717/how-to-disable-full-screen-animation-on-os-x-10-9) for older macOSes are also no faster.

Comment: I've always maintained [with no evidence other than anecdotal] that these transitions are there merely to prevent a halt, skip, jump jagginess & that bypassing them will take the same time, but look worse.

Comment: Plausible, "While the CPU is scurrying around, we might as well use that idle GPU for *something*..."  But my ancient Windows and Linux PCs, both with fewer cores, RAM, and GHz than my Macbook Pro, maximize a window too fast to even notice the rerendering.

Comment: It's not 'maximising' though - it's generating a whole new Space, registering it as extant, moving the current window to it & expanding to fit, whilst hiding the menu bar… Maximise you can do in a blink. Compare the speed to opt/click the green dot vs just click it. [Doesn't matter whether it fully maximises or not, just for a simple comparison test]

Comment: Green dot and control+command+F do the same, slow, thing for me.  Option-click green dot zooms just as slowly, but with more stuttering.  2019 MacBook Pro i9 radeon 5500M and Intel UHD 630 if that matters.
If there's yet another way to "maximise" (after all, this is Ask **Different**) that is instant, I'd accept that as an answer.

Comment: It's odd that opt/dot is slow. I'm on a 2010 Mac Pro & it's almost instantaneous. Fullscreen is slow [maybe a half second or so], but that's because of my guess above. [I actually never use fullscreen, for many reasons, one being I have two 27" screens, others are too many to list ;)

Comment: Why are Apple so incompetent that they cannot make their os fullscreen a video without a 1 SECOND delay! That's ridiculous. Even if they "make a whole new screen" etc. (a feature I DO NOT ACTUALLY WANT ANYWAY) that should not take a second to do. Incredible...

Comment: From about 2010 to 2016, arcane incantations could remove that delay.  But those stopped working in Catalina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, as of Catalina, macOS **cannot** instantly maximize a window.

I asked the IT departments of two organizations with which I am affiliated.  One has 500 power users, most of which use macOS.  The other has tens of thousands of users.  Neither department found a solution.  By now, any stronger proof might have to quote the macOS source code.